# ROW_NUMBER() function returns varchar value instead of int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, row-number

I'm using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in SQL Server to create a new column called `RowNumber`.

But when I later in the same query reference this new field in the `WHERE` statement I get this error, even though the field should be an integer:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'RowNumber' to data type int

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Node_base ORDER BY sum(c.Score) DESC) AS "RowNumber",  
   c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag, sum(Score)
FROM         
   t_input as c
WHERE 'RowNumber' < 11
GROUP BY c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag
ORDER BY c.Node_base desc
```

Comment: Mis-Diagnosis.  It can't convert the string `'RowNumber'` on line 6.  That's not a field name, that's just a string.  It may as well say `WHERE 'ThisIsAString' < 11`.  And as `<` needs both values to be the same type, it tries to convert the string to an INT, and fails.

Comment: 'This is a string literal.' "This is a quoted identifier." Please note the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reference a calculated column from the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause - and even if you could, single quotes introduce a string literal, rather than a column reference. Use a CTE or subquery.

```
;With Sums as (
    SELECT c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag,SUM(c.Score) as TotScore
    FROM t_input as c
    GROUP BY c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag
), NumberedRows as (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Node_base ORDER BY TotScore DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM Sums
)
select * from NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber <11
order by Node_base desc
```

There's no need to quote the name `RowNumber` at all - it's not a reserved word, and it contains no special characters.

Comment: Should I put it in a HAVING clause instead?

Comment: @MOLAP - No, you can't reference it from `HAVING` either.

Comment: @MOLAP - I've updated the query - I hadn't really read what you were trying to do inside the `ROW_NUMBER`, I think I've got it adjusted to what you wanted now.

Comment: Ok thanks. I ended up using a subquery saying: Select * from ( my query without the ORDER BY statement) as d WHERE where RowNumber <11
 order by d.Node_base desc

Answer (score 1):

Use `[RowNumber]` instead of `"RowNumber"`.

When [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is ON (default), all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers.

You'll also have to use a subquery to refer to `row_number()` in the `where` clause, like:

```
select  ...
from    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Node_base 
                    ORDER BY sum(Score) DESC) AS RowNumber
        ,       ...
        from    t_input
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   RowNumber < 11
```

Or in your case, I think you can just use `top`:

```
select  top 11 Node_base
,       Node_forslag
,       sum(Score)
from    t_input
group by
        Node_base
,       Node_forslag
order by
        sum(Score) desc
```

Comment: Don't think the `Top` will work, that'll return the first 11 rows, not the first 11 rows for each partition?

Comment: I have just tested the TOP function and it will not work in this case.

Comment: @JonEgerton: Yeah, top would return the top 11 `(base, forslag)` groups.  The `row_number()` variant does something weird: the top 11 `(base)` groups then grouped by `(base, forslag)`.  Not sure if that's what the OP is after.

Comment: Part 1 of this answer can make it work. (use a subquery in order to refer to the new field RowNumber.

Comment: Isn't this why `CROSS APPLY` was invented?

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
WHERE 'RowNumber' <11
```

You're comparing the string literal "RowNumber" to the number 11.

Just remove the quotes:

```
WHERE RowNumber <11
```

Comment: This results in: Invalid column name 'RowNumber'.

Comment: @MOLAP: you cannot reference a column you just define in the `SELECT` inside the same level `WHERE` - you need to wrap that statement that defines the `RowNumber` into a subquery or a CTE.

Comment: Yes - apply the filter like that doesn't work. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever says. (Was assuming you'd find that out and try to fix it yourself when you got the error - I'm trying not to spoon feed too much).

Answer (score 0):

select row_number() over (order by c.Node_base) as RowNumber, 
       c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag, sum(Score)

FROM  t_input as c

WHERE 'RowNumber' < 11

GROUP BY c.Node_base, c.Node_forslag

ORDER BY c.Node_base desc